# Set Method isn't working... it doesn't give the value to the variable

Tags: c#, class, get, set

Hell guys.

I am making this project with a Server, a Client and a Class library.
In the class library (which I added to the Server and the Client as Reference), I have for example an:

```
string f = "not working";
public void SetString(string n)
{
  f = n;
}

public string GetStr ()
{
 return f;
}
```

I have connected the client and the server and they are working properly, also the Get method is working but the SET METHOD isn't working?? When I call the set method from the client, it doesn't set the value that I am giving!!.
HttpChannel chan = new HttpChannel();

```
Tic obj = (Tic)Activator.GetObject(typeof(Tic), "http://127.0.0.1:9050/MyServer");

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan);
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string m = "working";
        obj.SetString(m);
    }
```

Again i repeat that the Get Method is working properly, but only the Set Method... and the problem is that it doesn't show me any error!!! it is just not giving the value to the string variable!!

Comment: How do you know it's not working? where's the code where you check the value is set?

Comment: i just call the Get method and it shows me the value of f ="not working"...

Comment: Did you call it right after Set method? `string m = "working"; obj.SetString(m); Console.WriteLine(obj.GetStr());`?

Comment: Or do you call it on a new istance of the class and get the default value of "not working"?

Comment: yes i did call after the se method

Comment: I wonder if it is a object lifetime issue.  If it is creating a new object instance each request, then the values won't persist.  You would need to persist them to a database or change the mode:  http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/12/net-remoting-part2-object-activation-lifetime-and-configuration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your set up correctly you are contacting a remote http server and calling a method which sets a variable value. You then contact that http server and ask for the value back, and you are getting the original value.

I'm not sure what sort of web "server" you are hosting but most of the time, servers only instantiate their classes when called upon.  So basically you are contacting a server, it instantiates whatever class containing the "f" string.  You set the value.  The server completes its job and kills the process.  Then you contact the server again asking for the value of "f", so it instantiates everything again, which means the value would be "not working".

Comment: Agreed. However the OP seems to have very little knowledge of C# basic things such as properties, therefore my suggestion still stands he needs to learn the basics before getting into complex client/server scenarios.

Comment: @spy This is my speculation as well, without seeing other code.  Probably need to use `WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton` instead of `.SingleCall` or better yet, persist data to a database so that the server can be stateless: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/12/net-remoting-part2-object-activation-lifetime-and-configuration/

Comment: @AaronLS, thnx for the advice... I tried SingleTon and now it is working thnx man D:

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Message {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public void Boz()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Message = "Working";
    }
}
```

Comment: no i didn't and to say the truth I really can't understand your code :(

Comment: @TarionSelmani please read the MSDN article about properties I linked to. I also suggest you read up on C# and OOP basics before trying to implement complex stuff such as services.